# on select get size height and width for multiple images by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I am using below code now i want to this for multiple image**

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    $("#logo_img").change(function (e) {
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
     }
   });
```

Here is HTML

```
<form action="ajax/product_images" id="uploadForm1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" id="logo_img" onchange='openFile(event)' onChange="validate(this.value)" />                    
    <input type="hidden" value="2" id="upload_id" name="upload_id" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: <form action="ajax/product_images"  id="uploadForm1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"   id="logo_img"  onchange='openFile(event)' onChange="validate(this.value)" />    
          <input type="hidden" value="2" id="upload_id"  name="upload_id" />   
          
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;" value="Upload"/>
        </form>

Comment: Do you mean if the user selects multiple images in the file upload?

Comment: Yes, user will upload multiple images so it should be alert now, because i am having validation for every image select image time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `for`-loop:

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#logo_img").change(function(e) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var file = this.files[i];
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      console.log(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="ajax/product_images" id="uploadForm1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" id="logo_img" />
  <input type="hidden" value="2" id="upload_id" name="upload_id" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please mark as answer if this is what you were aiming for.